# when i use screenmanager no thing displayed om my screen kivymd python

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

When I use screenmanager nothing displayed om my screen kivymd python
I don't get any error so that means no bug in my code, but it doesn't display anything, and anyone of the both screens

this is my code :

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton, MDRectangleFlatButton, MDIconButton, MDFloatingActionButton
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel, MDIcon


class firstscreen(Screen):
    pass


class secondscreen(Screen):
    pass


class windowmanager(ScreenManager):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file('sc.kv')


class Yom(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Yom().run()
```

and this is the sc.kv file

```
windowmanager:
        firstscreen:
        secondscreen:
        
    <firstscreen>:
        name:'firstscreen'
        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text:"calc moy"
            pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
            on_release:MDApp.root.current='secondscreen'
            
                            
    <secondscreen>:
        name:'secondscreen'
        MDLabel:
            text:'welcome to calcu screen'
            halign:'center'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, that you did not capitalize the first letter of your classes. Kivy is very picky about this and refuses to load the screen correctly when you don't do this.

On a side note:

Classes should always be capitalized and use [PascalCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) as per [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names)

Corrected Code:

main.kv:

```
WindowManager:
FirstScreen:
secondscreen:

<FirstScreen>:
    name:'firstscreen'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:"calc moy"
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        on_release:MDApp.root.current='secondscreen'
        
                        
<SecondScreen>:
    name:'secondscreen'
    MDLabel:
        text:'welcome to calcu screen'
        halign:'center'
```

main.py:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton, MDRectangleFlatButton, MDIconButton, MDFloatingActionButton
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel, MDIcon

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Yom(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file('main.kv')
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Yom().run()
```